# Is there any problem in installing ClamAV (or any antivirus) in Ubuntu with any antivirus installed in Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, antivirus

I using Ubuntu along with Windows 10 (Dual Booted), and using Quick Heal Antivirus in Windows. I read a lot about ClamAV antivirus, and as it is good to install antivirus. Is there any problem in installing ClamAV (or any antivirus) in Ubuntu with any antivirus installed in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Well, as far as I know, the answer is "NO". Basically, the two antiviruses have no influence one over the other. They are installed on two different OSs, each one of them on a different partition. It's like two dogs guarding two different gardens.

The main difference is that you can use your ClamAV Antivirus to scan Windows from inside Ubuntu. But even in this situation, the two antiviruses will not interfere.

Answer (score 0):

No, the AVs only scan and have impact in the OS which they are installed in and thus there is no problem as the OSs are completely separate in a dual-boot.

Answer (score 0):

No way, each system installed on your PC, even if they reside on the same hard disk, are completely separated from each other.

You can safely install ClamAV on your Ubuntu system.